# Язык: из истории слова

Tags: этимология

В книге Н. М. Шанского "Лингвистические детективы" в статье "Дело о прилагательном *лингвистический* и глаголе *звать*" есть такой абзац:

> Сравнение русского слова с соответствующим словом в других славянских языках (ср. болг. *език*, пол. jẹzyk, чеш. jazyk и т. д.) позволяет восстановить общеславянскую форму этого существительного как *ẹzyk, где позже возник протетический (вставной) **j**, а **е** (в русскомʼа) восходит к звукосочетанию en (ср. *семя – семени*).

Я не могу понять, что за русское ***'а*** и что значит "**е** восходит к звукосочетанию en". Не могли бы вы объяснить?

Прочитать статью полностью можно [здесь](http://www.rulit.me/books/lingvisticheskie-detektivy-read-80092-2.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Я не могу понять, что за русское 'а (это Шанский так криво передает [jа]?)

'а - это палатализирующий звук а.

> что значит "е восходит к звукосочетанию en".

Какое слово тут непонятно? "Восходит к" (чеу-то) означает "является рефлексом" (чего-то). Было в каком-то предке (обычно - ближайшем) языка  некоторое сочетание, которое в языке-потомке стало другим.

Здесь речь о том, что в праславянском (и/или позднем ПИЕ) было такое сочетание en, которое в общеславянском превратилось в ẹ (Е носовое, юс малый) которое в начале слова приобрело протетический Йот и в таком виде закрепилось в большинстве славянских. А в русском последовательно реализовалось в я (='а).

Статью не читал, но тут все понятно. Ничего кривого, все вполне корректно.